# Is there a way to detect an ELF binary is broken/tampered or not?

Tags: unix, elf

How do I programatically detect whether an ELF binary is tampered or broken?

For example, If I delete second half of an ELF binary (or a library shared object) and paste random text, this will corrupt it and it will not work after. I want to detect whether an Unix ELF 32 binary or UNIX shared C library object is subjected to this.

Thanks.

Comment: e.g. something like [Samhain](http://la-samhna.de/samhain/) or [AFICK](http://afick.sourceforge.net/) or [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) or [Aide](http://aide.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: No, my application will work on a proxy server. I know it is kinda wierd feature, but I need to detect a binary whether tampered or not. Some colleagues told me about readelf executable. Now, I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you thinking about, but the "correct way" to validate a ELF binary is to use a HASH like SHA-1, MD5, etc.

When you create the ELF file, then you also create the "signature file" using this HASH algorithm, i.e. MD5 and validate the result.

For example on Solaris you can create a MD5, SHA1, SHA256 digest using the command

```
# digest -a [algorithm] [/path/to/file] {-v}
```

So, to validate the "/bin/sh" to prevent modifcations, you should make

```
# digest -v -a md5 /bin/sh
md5 (/bin/sh) = f4ad35f5246f817d68f4895463d79b09

# digest -v -a sha1 /bin/sh
sha1 (/bin/sh) = aa3843a19f2225458d7e3e765f44e229a09c0ad0

# digest -v -a sha256 /bin/sh
sha256 (/bin/sh) = a5e1a0062bb6600f06e029ce58f500169e966400b173b7fba504d5cd4635f291
```

Here you have more examples in spanish [Where is MD5 in Solaris and HowTo Use it](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2010/04/donde-esta-md5-en-solaris.html)

If hashing is not the solution, you can use *(on Solaris)* commands to verify the ELF as
*elfdump* and *ldd*

You can use the *ldd* with *-iv* to verify the shared libraries initialization

```
itily@openzooey:~/hello.world$ ldd -iv hello

   find object=libc.so.1; required by hello
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
   find version=libc.so.1
        libc.so.1 (SYSVABI_1.3) =>       /lib/libc.so.1
        libc.so.1 (SUNWprivate_1.1) =>   /lib/libc.so.1

   object=/lib/libc.so.1; filter for /usr/lib/ld.so.1

   object=/lib/libc.so.1; filter for libm.so.2

   find object=libm.so.2; required by /lib/libc.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2

   find object=libc.so.1; required by /lib/libm.so.2
   find version=libc.so.1
        libc.so.1 (SUNW_1.1) =>  /lib/libc.so.1
        libc.so.1 (SUNWprivate_1.1) =>   /lib/libc.so.1

   init object=/lib/libc.so.1
```

To generate a checksum of ELF you can use the option *-k*

```
itily@openzooey:~/hello.world$ elfdump -k hello

elf checksum: 0x8922
```

But, if you don't have a *trusted ELF* to compare, it's a bit dificult, I think.

I hope this is what you are looking for,

Urko,

Comment: No. Hashing is not a solution. I do not have any access or control where binary is created. My application should give the answer when  encounters at the first time.

Comment: But, if you don't have access to binary, how you know when is corrupted or modified?